# Tableadapter.fill times out when table is empty

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, timeout, tableadapter

I have a View that i am trying to use to fill a TableAdapter with. In my code i fill the table adapter properly the first time, filter my bindingsource and use datarowviews to loop through the rows of data and perform the updates needed (done by a stored procedure). Now the problem is, after these updates take place, i need to fill the tableadapter again so that it reflects these changes. Sometimes the View i am using will have no results, other times it may. I can't give a specific example as the data is work sensitive but i'll try and create a simplified example

```
_taMyView.Fill(_dsMyConnection.MyView)
_bsMyView.Filter = "Number = 1"
For Each drvMyViewRow in _bsMyView
   Do Stuff
   'stored procedure that updates MyTable (what the view was created from)
Next

_taMyView.Fill(_dsMyConnection.MyView)
_bsMyView.Filter = "Number = 0"
```

This is the exact Error "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Okay, you'll notice that i fill my view, then filter those results on the column Number equal to 1. I loop through all those results and update the table my view is created off of. After exiting the loop i hit the second .fill which times out after about 20 seconds. After testing, this time out only seems to occur when MyView does not hold any records. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some extra tidbits. I use Visual Studio 2010 and sqlserver 2008. All work is done in VB.NET. Also, during debugging, i paused on the second fill, went to Toad for Data Analysts and ran a SELECT * FROM MyView which did not time out and returned the empty result table in about 19 seconds. I have also tried doing a dispose on the tableadapter before the second fill but it has a similar time out. Sorry if this answer seems obvious or something, i'm only an Intern and am still learning the language.

**EDIT**

`MyAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0`

That seems to have done the trick, from my understanding that lets it run until it finishes (SQLServer will shut it down if the connection stays open longer than it allows). The ta.fill runs at about the same pace as Toad coming in around 19-20 second mark and does not error after multiple tests. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

19 seconds? How many rows? How complicated is the view? If a query takes 19 seconds from Toad or Management Studio it is quite feasible that it takes double that from your VB.NET code. Perhaps you should think about increasing the CommandTimeout value (default is, I believe, 30 seconds) and/or optimizing the structure if you think 19 seconds is too long (I certainly do).

Comment: The view is basically a SELECT * FROM MyTable Where IsActive = 1. MyTable's results increase and decrease periodically from a separate application that runs in short intervals but the table usually contains 500,000+ rows of data. No user interacts with the application as it only sends out emails in intervals (the application will be set to run every 10 minutes, it currently takes about 1.5-2 minutes to run completely) so the time it takes for results to return isn't a huge issue. How would i go about increasing the CommandTimeout? TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionTimeout is read only.

Comment: You need to ask yourself: do you really want to potentially pull 500K+ rows into your table adapter? Do you really want to scan through 500K+ rows to find the one or two (or 0) to populate into your table adapter? Anyway, ConnectionTimeout <> CommandTimeout. You should be able to say something like `MyAdapter.SelectCommandTimeout = 90` or more (sorry, if anything I'm C# not VB.Net).

Comment: I don't really think i have much of a choice. The table is used to store rows from files we receive. At some point every single one of the rows in that table is sent in an email somewhere or marked to be ignored when it comes in (they arrive in much smaller volumes but we store the data for awhile before removal in case a problem occurs and we need to go back and look at it) There isn't a smaller table i could pull the information from either so as far as i know i'm stuck with 500k rows lol.